# Is it possible to use a high resolution timer from within an iframe for benchmarking absolute performance against the parent document?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I am trying to benchmark the performance implications of various iframe setups.

I would like to know how long it takes from the start of the root document until a certain point within an iframe.

One option is to use `Date.now()` and compare that to the host's `performance.timeOrigin` of the root page like so:

```html
<body>
   <iframe> <!-- cross origin iframe -->
     <script>console.log(Date.now())</script>
   </iframe>
   <script>console.log(performance.timeOrigin)</script>
</body>
```

The issue is that `Date.now()` offers inaccurate times and I would rather use a high resolution timer offered by the `performance` API.

Trying to use `performance.now()` gives me a relative duration since the start of the current frame, however I am trying to obtain the relative duration since the start of the rootmost document.

So if you imagine something like this:

```html
<body>
   <iframe>
     <script>console.log(performance.now())</script> // 8ms
   </iframe>
   <script>console.log(performance.now())</script> // 30ms
</body>
```

There does not appear to be a way to get a high resolution absolute time using the performance API. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to get the values dynamically or just want to see the logs?

Comment: why not just `<iframe onload="console.log(performance.now())">` ?

Comment: @skara9 OP doesn't want to find the load time. He wants to find the page performance, i.e. JS execution time.

Comment: Actually the load event may as well do if you just want to see logs&mdash;just add `onload="console.log('OUT:', performance.now())"` then in the iframe `console.log('IN:', performance.now());` then add the two values together. Easy peasy. If you want to collect the data programmatically you may want to use something like Puppeteer which can listen for logs and you can just add them together.

Comment: It appears I can just do `performance.timeOrigin + performance.now()` which is equivalent to Date.now()

Comment: @DavidAlsh maybe you should post that as an answer